# MyFaces Commons Validator maven dependency repository

Tags: maven, repository, myfaces

Seems like i am having a hard time finding the repository manager for this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone give me a hand on this :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

The correct dependency should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfaces-validators20</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency can be found in Maven Central public repository: 
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.myfaces.commons%7Cmyfaces-validators20%7C1.0.2%7Cjar